# LNK1104 When trying to link with boost_filesystem*.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, boost-filesystem

I'm using CMake to create a cross platform project using some Boost libraries. I have used the following command to create the libraries.

```
.\b2.exe --prefix=C:/Boost install --with-python --with-system --with-filesystem address-model=32 toolset=msvc-12.0 link=shared threading=multi --layout=tagged --build-type=complete
```

The project links fine with the python and system libraries, but when it tries to link with the file system library, it fails. It is looking for "libboost_filesystem*.lib" (which doesn't exist) and then uses the "boost_python*.lib" and "boost_system*.lib" files with no problems.

My top level CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)

add_subdirectory(shape)
add_subdirectory(py_shape)

#define sources and executable
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "renderer2d")
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})

#find python
find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#detect and add SFML
#this line checks a cmake file for hints on where to find cmake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules"     ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
#find any version 2.x of SFML
#see the FindSFML.cmake file for additional details and instructions
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

#find and include Boost python libraries
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

#link all found libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}     ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} shape)

#install target
install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
```

And my lone source file for this exe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "../shape/inc/Shape.hpp"
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    Py_Initialize();

    //need to insert working directory into path
    path working_directory = absolute("./").normalize();
    PyObject* sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyList_Insert(sys_path, 0,     PyString_FromString(working_directory.string().c_str()));

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "renderer2d");
    Shape shape;
    shape.Initialize();

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
      sf::Event event;
      while(window.pollEvent(event))
      {
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
          window.close();
        if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
          if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Q)
            window.close(); 
          else if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::U)
            shape.Update();
          else if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S)
            shape.SetGreen(255);
        }
      }

      window.clear();
      window.draw(*shape.GetShape());
      window.display();
    }
  } catch(error_already_set){PyErr_Print();}

  return 0;
}
```

So, why would it be trying to link against "libboost_filesystem" rather than "boost_filesystem"?

Comment: So you are saying that the naming of boost libraries is inconsistent?

Comment: Because the filesystem developer works on Linux, where libs are generally named `libx` instead of `x.lib`?

Comment: Boost has an auto-linking feature. Can you try disabling that by adding `target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<BOOL:${MSVC}>:BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB>)`?

Comment: Fraser, thank you, that did the trick. What exactly did it do though?

Comment: @rearden It disables #pragma directives inside Boost that link your program with corresponding *.lib files automatically. See https://github.com/boostorg/config/blob/89fd23ad0a4e7786e57c2ac9e4ffcc1015020477/include/boost/config/auto_link.hpp#L381-L399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that Boost has [an auto-linking feature](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking) which can be useful if you're not using CMake.

To disable this feature, you simply have to apply a preprocessor definition as shown in the table in the [docs for Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/index.html#boost_config.configuring_boost_for_your_platform.user_settable_options):

> `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`: Tells the config system not to automatically select which libraries to link against. Normally if a compiler supports #pragma lib, then the correct library build variant will be automatically selected and linked against, simply by the act of including one of that library's headers. This macro turns that feature off.

To add a preprocessor definition via CMake, you can use the [`target_compile_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_compile_definitions.html) command.  If you want to limit the definition to just the MSVC compiler for example, you can use a [generator expression](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html):

```
target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<BOOL:${MSVC}>:BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB>)
```